# MVC Async actions behave as Sync when Session_Start is enabled at Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

(Blank application created using MVC 5.2.3 and Net Framework 4.5.2 from Visual Studio 2015). Sample shows controller with async methods to show progress in an indicator (GetProgressAsync) assuming server is busy for a while (CommitAsync):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
public static int Progress = 0;

public async Task<ActionResult> GetProgressAsync()
{
    Task<ActionResult> task = Task.Run<ActionResult>(() =>
    {
        var result = new ContentResult();
        result.Content = string.Format("Progreso: {0}", Progress);
        return result;
    });

    return await task;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> CommitAsync()
{
    Task<ActionResult> task = Task.Run<ActionResult>(() =>
    {
        Progress = 0;

        while (Progress < 100)
        {
            Progress++;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        var result = new ContentResult();
        result.Content = string.Format("{0} : Commit completado", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        return result;
    });

    return await task;
}
}
```

If methods Session_Start/Session_End are not enabled in Global.asax.cs, the controller will behave as async, as it should, and progress of the task can be monitored (i.e. from the browser).

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}

//WARNING: habilitar estos métodos hace que no funcionen las llamadas Async/Await
//WARNING: enabling this methods hang Async/Await support
//protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
//{
//    // TODO
//}

//protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
//{
//    // TODO
//}
}
```

The bug is identified when session methods Session_Start/Session_End are enabled. The controller will only work as async for the first request. Subsequent CommitAsync requests will hang the app and requests to GetProgressAsync will not be handled until CommitAsync finishes.

Answer (score 0):

It works with this attribute on the controller:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```